# Using a pre made sql query to get table structure

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm rather new at database management, so this might not be feasible, but I got a handful of SQL select queries, rather long ones at that. What I'd like is to get the table column names and structure, without access to the actual database, so as to get a map of all this queries.

context: All we have are the queries used to output tables that will be given to us latter.

This need not be done with actual SQL code, maybe a short script in other language or a utility somebody knows of (but I do have MySQL workbench)

Comment: This sounds like a lot of wishful thinking. Dump it in your text editor and pick it apart systematically.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **CREATE TABLE** statement in front of your select queries to get the column names.

You cannot infer data types or keys from select queries.

For column names do something like:

```
drop table if exists your_table_name;
create table your_table_name
select *
  from ...
```

where the select * portion is replaced by the select queries you have.
Then to see the column names in a friendlier way you can do:

```
show create table your_table_name;
```

or

```
desc your_table_name;
```